# How to read each of a multidimensional array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need the help of this amazing community :)

Maybe the way I am declaring, creating my arrays are wrong, but I am adding content to an array of array and I am not being able to get nothing from it.

This is my code (edit with my current code)

```
var arr_size = raw_data.length;
```

var label_ar = {};

```
$.each(raw_data, function() {
    var key = this.label;
  if (typeof label_ar[key] === 'undefined'){
            label_ar.key = {};
            label_ar.key.label = this.label;
            label_ar.key.Analyze = 0;
            label_ar.key.Verify = 0;
            label_ar.key.Closed = 0;
            label_ar.key.Build = 0;
            label_ar.key.Integrate = 0;
        //  console.dir(label_ar.key);
    }
    c_state = (this.state);
    label_ar.key[c_state] = (parseInt(this.value));
});

$.each(label_ar, function(i,v) {
    // console.dir(i, e);
    console.log("loop");
    $.each(label_ar[i], function(i,v) {
            console.log(i, v);
        });
    });
```

I’ve noticed console.dir show the content but at first it shows []

and length label_ar.length is equal a zero (not sure how)

This is a snapshot of my console
[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUAop.png)

What I am doing wrong?

Looks like label_ar has only the content of the last loop

This is raw_data
[raw_data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aP7GK.png)

My output out be many arrays with something like: 
label – “CC" 
Analyze – 1 
Verify – 2 
Closed – 4
Build – 0
Integrate – 2

Comment: You should show what is in `raw_data`. Also I'd remove `label_ar[c_label] = [];` and change it to `label_ar[c_label] = {};` since you probably want an object instead of an array there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to “fix” it, thanks for the last response I saw I need to use objects not arrays of array, but an object with array

If anyone has a better, efficient solution, it’s welcome.

```
var arr_size = raw_data.length;
var label_ar = {};

$.each(raw_data, function() {
  if (typeof label_ar[this.label] == 'undefined'){
            label_ar[this.label] = {};
            label_ar[this.label].label = this.label;
            label_ar[this.label].Analyze = 0;
            label_ar[this.label].Verify = 0;
            label_ar[this.label].Closed = 0;
            label_ar[this.label].Build = 0;
            label_ar[this.label].Integrate = 0;
    }
    label_ar[this.label][this.state] = (parseInt(this.value));
});

 console.dir(label_ar);
```

It’s working now :)

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm going to make some styling suggestions - hopefully you'll find this helpful.  Supposing that I do not know what is in raw data, besides that it is an array.  of course, you don't need to declare arrays ahead of time, and you should generally prefer camel-case in javascript

```
// the map function takes an array, and returns an array
// the first argument, d, is each element of raw data
var labelAr = rawData.map(function(d){

    // we can create a multidimensional array by returning an
    // Array literal, however you should really use an object
    // if you plan to have non numeric keys
    return {
       Integrate: 0,
       Analyze: 0,
       Closed: 0,
       Verify: 0,
       Build: 0,
       Label: d.label // this can come from d
       Value: d.value // this can come from d
    };
});
```

Besides that it is difficult to help you without seeing what is in raw_data

Comment: Raw data is an array of objects, inside each I have something like (label: X, state: Closed, value: 5), (label: X, state: Analyze, value: 3).
The problem is is I don’t have all states for each data, and I want an output that has “0” if it does not exists, so I can use the data to plot a chart

raw_data is originally from json, but I am using the data parsed, since I am using this data in other parts of my application and I don’t want to do many ajax calls, also I am using only the data that I need for the chart here. 

Thanks